# PuTTY Connection to virtual machine

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox

I'm trying to use PuTTY to remotely connect to my CentOS currently being run on Oracle Virtualbox. The problem is that I can't seem to find the correct IP address. Here's what I get after pressing 'ifconfig'.

[image]

I've done this on a school computer, and I remember that instead of a "10.0.x" format the IP address was "192.168.xx" and it was under something called "ens" rather than "eno0s3."

Is there any way that I could find out how to connect? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you've configured Virtualbox.  On the assumption that the output you've shared (text is better than an image, next time, since images can't be indexed) is from the guest OS, and that you've got things configured correctly, it might be either `10.0.2.15` or `192.168.122.1`

Try them and see if it works.

Comment: 10.0.2.15 is the address VirtualBox assigns for a virtual interface type 'NAT' which relays via the host stack and its real interface(s) and address(es); to reach it inbound you must use the (or an) address of the host and the forwarded/NATted port which is often different from the guest's port. Unless of course the host is itself virtualized ....

Comment: Yes, it depends on how it's all configured.  10.0.2.15 *might* be what you describe, but doesn't have to be.

Answer (score -2):

`hostname -I` should give you the IP address

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  The OP showed they've already got a list of IP addresses from `ifconfig`, so what additional information would they get from `hostname -I`?